# simplesamPHP not recognising windows live auth

Tags: php, wso2, saml, windows-live, simplesamlphp

I have a simplesamlphp api script which just checks if the user is logged in, then displays the attributes.

Its seems to work with a facebook idp. However microsoft keeps attempting to login.

Here is the basic code.

```
<?php

require_once('/opt/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');   
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('wso2-sp');
if (!$as->isAuthenticated()) {
    $as->login();
}
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);

?>
```

Note im using a wso2 identity server (5.0.0).

The simplesamlphp example works perfect. Mine however keeps saying the following on the windows live login page.

```
Because you're accessing sensitive info, you need to verify your password.
```

I can see once i login, it redirects back to my php file, which then obviously sends it back to windows live. If i redirect back to simplesamlPHP example, it goes through first time. I really think its the api im using.

Perhaps someone has seen this before, and could advise a way to get round this.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If i redirect to a separate page, and display sessions, i see that there is a value, "loginCompleted". Its seems the simpleSAML_Auth_Simple api is not recognising this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect uri need to be `https://[wso2 is address]/commonauth`

However i was still unable to get attributes from this service.